# How do I save terminal output to a file?

Tags: command-line

How do I save the output of a command to a file from terminal?

That is if my command gives some output and it is printed directly on terminal but I want it in some text file or may be other kind of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add right sided arrow after your command:

```
someCommand > someFile.txt
```

Or if you want to append data(will create file if it doesn't exist):

```
someCommand >> someFile.txt
```